# SFMC Query Console

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am new to SFMC, battling it out on SQL console, I am finding it quite tough to debug SQL queries, often to run the queries and check in DE.It is time consuming , having very hard to find out the line no error as SQL DEVELOPER, etc. I have already gone through Adam's blog, but for some scenarios, we can't split the queries.How SFMC gurus deal with this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, it's not very clear what your problem or question is. Generally speaking, the more detail that you can provide (and the narrower your question), the better.

Comment: Get an own Microsoft SQL Server with the Management Software behind it or just write clean code ;) there is no sl console or whatsoever, if you want help regarding the. Awe and your query then we need more information what you have tried and how the data is structured / shall be structured

Answer (score 4):

I can understand your frustration. Though your question could indeed be more specific (so we can better help you), I do understand you're looking for a good *approach* to writing SQL server in SFMC.

I would give these points as advice:

1. Read the [Query Activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_query_activity.htm) docs carefully and then test your code often in the Query Activity interface by clicking '**Validate**'.
2. Salesforce has recently (a couple of days ago in fact) released the [Query Studio](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FP3yFUAT) on AppExchange which allows you to validate queries based on target DEs
3. If working with SQL server continues to be a struggle - which it appears to be for many SFMC users - consider using [DESelect](https://deselect.io?utm_source=sfse&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=sf-se-12) (an addon for SFMC) that provides you a nifty UI instead of writing SQL

I hope this helps and if it does, please leave an upvote. ;)
Otherwise feel free to ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alamo. It is really a great help.

Comment: cheers @samy , to show on Salesforce StackExchange that someone's answer helped, you can upvote their answer, but in addition you can also select their answer as "best answer" (which only the original poster of the question can do)

Comment: Oh wow, this Query Studio is such a game changer. No more writing SQL queries blind!